# Why do you 'contribute' money to your own Health Savings Account, not 'deposit' it?

Tags: word-meaning

> While you can use the funds in an HSA at any time to pay for qualified medical expenses, you may **contribute** to an HSA only if you have a High Deductible Health Plan (HDHP) — generally a health plan (including a Marketplace plan) that only covers preventive services before the deductible. - healthcare.gov

> To give something that is or becomes part of a larger whole. - contribute, wiktionary

Putting in money to my savings account does not give money to become part of a larger whole. I know that Health Savings Account is tax-free savings account for the account owner's medical expense. It is not to donate or make part of public fund.

Why do you say 'contribute' instead of 'deposit' on HSA?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is langauge that is specific to the way that health insurance works.  Often the fund will take contributions from the individual and the individual's employer.  Both are giving something (money) into something that becomes part of a larger whole. And this whole can't be accessed unless the individual becomes sick and needs to go to hospital.

The language of "deposit" and "withdrawal" is used of saving accounts in which money that has been deposited can be taken out at the saver's choice.  This is unlike an HSA.  You can't withdraw money from such an account, so it doesn't make sense to talk about "depositing" it either.

Comment: US health aka medical insurance generally, and HSA particularly, covers medical care much more broadly than just hospitalization. It is true HSA is normally used for 'qualified' medical expenses (for self/spouse/dedepents, mostly excluding insurance); you _can_ 'distribute' (take out, withdraw, whatever) HSA money and use it for other purposes but that is subject to tax _plus_ a 20% penalty unless you are elderly or disabled.